# Get a 401 error (authorization required) when adding parameters to my query

Tags: php, xml, oauth, google-data-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to get a user contacts data through the Google Data API and am facing a problem: I get this 401 error message when I specify a parameter to my query (for ex in my case it's max-results=9999 as per query 1), while I can access the content (but limited to 25 entries...) with no pb when I don't add any query parameter (as per query 2).

Query 1: ...google's address.../m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=9999

Query 2: ...google's address.../m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

(I tried with both simple http and https scopes and requests but same result...)

I am using jrconlin's PHP oauthsimple library found here.

https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/blob/master/php/example.php

Sorry guys if my question is trivial but I have been banging my head for a few hours now by rereading jrconlin's code and google's guide but really don't see where the mistake is!! Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Well, that's a really large value for max-results.  What happens if you set `max-results` explicitly to 25 or smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is typical between different Google Products (not just Youtube or Sites, as cited below)

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html

> The max-results parameter specifies the maximum number of results that
>   should be included in the result set. This parameter works in
>   conjunction with the start-index parameter to determine which results
>   to return. For example, to request the second set of 10 results – i.e.
>   results 11-20 – set the max-results parameter to 10 and the
>   start-index parameter to 11. The default value of this parameter is
>   25, **and the maximum value is 50**. However, for displaying lists of
>   videos, we recommend that you set the max-results parameter to 10.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=781d988ee3fe2f09&hl=en

> You must make multiple requests to get all pages in order to get all
>   results.  That is, you must follow each next link, and aggregate the
>   results.  We limit accepted values of max-results for performance
>   reasons.